# Is there a way to authenticate users in an ASP.NET Core MVC web app using Azure AD, but with a your own login page, not using Microsoft’s login portal

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to make my own login page for an ASP.NET Core MVC web app using Azure AD (not Azure AD B2C). But I can't find a good way to authenticate a user without using Microsoft's own login page. I don't want to use that.

So is there a way I can authenticate the username and the password, and get a boolean in return? The ASP.NET Core MVC web app uses C#.

Answer (score 0):

The use of email and password is officially allowed to log in , but it's not recommended. For safety reasons, please evaluate your own after use.

You can [read official doc first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc). And from the http request details, we can find it support username and password to log in.

```
// Line breaks and spaces are for legibility only.  This is a public client, so no secret is required.

POST {tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=user.read%20openid%20profile%20offline_access
&username=MyUsername@myTenant.com
&password=SuperS3cret
&grant_type=password
```